# conditional rendering react component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

**Problem Statement**
React element not loading on conditional rendering

**What I have done till now**

I have a simple condition and I want to render components based on that. 
Here's how it looks like. I want to render IoMdAdd when true

```
true
  ? (()=>(<Link><IoMdAdd size="25"/></Link>))
  : (()=>(<Link><IoIosHeartEmpty size="25"/></Link>))
```

conversely, I want to show IoIosHeartEmpty when the condition is false

```
false
  ? (()=>(<Link><IoMdAdd size="25"/></Link>))
  : (()=>(<Link><IoIosHeartEmpty size="25"/></Link>))
```

**Current behavior**
It doesn't show anything. The element doesn't appear in the dom when I do inspect element.

**Expected behavior**
Show one of the components based on the condition

**Edit**
Since y'all are asking for more code, let me paste the entire component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "@reach/router";
import { IoIosHeartEmpty, IoMdAdd } from "react-icons/io";
import { connect } from "react-redux"
class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div className="wishlist-icon">
                {(localStorage.getItem("accessLevel") == "Admin" && this.state.loggedInUser.accessLevel == "Admin") ? (<Link to="AdminPage"><IoMdAdd size="25" /></Link>) : (<Link to="UserPage"><IoIosHeartEmpty size="25" /></Link>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        loggedInUser: state.loggedInUser
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header)
```

If the user is admin, I want to show him an icon that links him to the admin page, otherwise, I want to take him to the user page.

Comment: We probably need more code . Where do you wrote this ? in your render?

Comment: The code in your edit looks fine. do either of the links work without the ternary?

Comment: They work without the ternary. They work if I don't enclose them in a pair of paranthesis and <Link> <Link/> element too. I want to have the link element so that a user can go to those links.

Comment: This is the error I get when I take away the parenthesis
```
  3 | ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  4 | // startsWith(string, search) - Check if `string` starts with `search`
  5 | var startsWith = function startsWith(string, search) {
> 6 |   return string.substr(0, search.length) === search;
  7 | };
  8 | 
  9 | ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: The parenthesis aren't necessary, so remove them and it works? or was that a mistake in your comment

Comment: The parenthesis werent a mistake. I pasted the error it shows when I remove them. Coz I thought so too, that the parenthesis shouldnt be necessary.

Comment: What is this referring to? `> 6 | return string.substr(0, search.length) === search;`

Comment: No clue. There's no such code in my project and I tried putting the error on google and had no help. So, I am here.

Comment: Your error is there, so, unless you can find it, we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
{true? 
  <Link><IoMdAdd size="25"/></Link>
: <Link><IoIosHeartEmpty size="25"/></Link>
}
```

Comment: hope this can help you. If it worked I would be happy if you mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score -1):

Can you use this in the JSX?

```
{myBool ? (
  <Link><IoMdAdd size="25"/></Link>
) : (
  <Link><IoIosHeartEmpty size="25"/></Link>
)}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not returning React components instead a function, so try this:

```
true
  ? (<Link><IoMdAdd size="25"/></Link>)
  : (<Link><IoIosHeartEmpty size="25"/></Link>)
```